# Someone to explain a part of this jQuery code to me using the dhtmlxcombo plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dhtml

I have this code fragment

```
var combo = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone4", "alfa4", 230);
    combo.loadXML("create_store2.php");
    combo.attachEvent("onChange", onChangeFunc);
    combo.enableFilteringMode(true, "select_store.php");
    function onChangeFunc() {
        var d=combo.getSelectedValue();
        var product=$("#selProduct");
        product.find('option').remove();

        $.ajax({
            url: "select_store2.php",
            data: "store=" + d,
```

My questions are what are those 3 files used for, and why we need three different files to be called.

**Fragment 1:**

```
combo.loadXML("create_store2.php");
```

`create_store2` seams it returns some XML data, some `<option>` tags.

**Fragment 2:**

```
combo.enableFilteringMode(true, "select_store.php");
```

`select_store` seams it returns some XML data, some `<option>` tags.

**Fragment 3:**

```
url: "select_store2.php",
```

`select_store2` seams it returns some JSON data, this is probably the result of the autocomplete call.

Comment: What's the difference between the two php files?

Comment: There are 3 files, not 2. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used the [dhtmlx components](http://dhtmlx.com/) but the API does give off some serious red flags, data can really only be loaded with [xml responses](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxcombo%3afiltering) ?

Here's what I gathered from the API.

`loadXML` loads additional options from an XML file (i take it you can set these in script too)

`enableFilteringMode` enables suggestions as you type, i think the `create_store2.php` call in `loadXML` gives the combo also its initional data set.

the jquery ajax call I presume changes the contents of a combo box with the values supplied by `select_store2.php` filtered by the selected value of `combo` but i'd need to see the rest of the code to know for sure. Since this is jquery this data is returned in json and I presume manually processed later on in the code.